# Creating a minimal input field and button with Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a very minimal input field with a glyphicon button.

Unfortunately there is a white border even though i have cleared everything.

HTML:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
  <input type="text" class="form-control transp" placeholder="Search">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="transp btn btn-default " type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
  </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.transp {
            background:none!important;
            background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8)!important;
            border:none!important;
            border-color:none!important;
            text-shadow:none!important;
            box-shadow:none!important;
        }
```

See this Bootply Example as a demonstration of the white button border:

[Bootply - Button Border](http://www.bootply.com/c6duZob6Je)

Comment: It's always better to have a live example of the markup so people can test/debug the code, so I removed the screenshot and added a Bootply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The margin on  `.input-group-btn:last-child>.btn` is the cause.

Add this to your CSS:

```
.input-group-btn:last-child>.transp {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: `.input-group-btn:last-child>.transp {
  margin-left: 0;
}` selector could be used instead of !important and prevent all `.input-group-btn:last-child>.btn` from being overridden